# How to compare two divs?

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

Want to make a switch function to compare one of the three randomly selected divs with the class "cards" and for example a div with the id=ímg-1'.
The random variable isnt't a div but I don't know how to make it one, or take its id to compare with the card1 variable.

```
var card1 = document.getElementById('img-1')

function changeCard() {
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.cards').length);

switch (random){
    case card1:
     play()
     break;
}
}
```

One of the three divs:

```
<div id="img-1" class="cards"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is it you want to compare? Or do you mean switch as in 'switch positions of 2 div elements'?

Comment: What should happen with the other cards? I mean when the random element matches to `card1` you call `play` function, how about the othere elements, are there functions with a different name to call? I'm asking this, because it is probably possible to get rid of the `switch` altogether. You can pick a random element from a jQuery object like this: `$('.cards')[Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.cards').length)]`.

Comment: For the other two cards there would be another function called, but I left that out for the sake of the example.

Comment: It would be easier to store the functions into an array, and just create a random integer with which you can point to an index in that array, call a function like `array[rnd]();`.

Comment: I don't how to do that though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you've `card2` and `card3` too, and as you said in a comment, there will be different functions to execute for all the cards. If that's the case, the `scwitch` comparing a random div to the variables is overly complicated, you can simply create an array of the functions and call a function randomly, like this (the example array contains some invented function names, replace those with your own functions):

```
const actions = [play, deal, win];

function changeCard() {
  const len = $('.cards').length,
    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
  if (actions.length <= len) {
    actions[rnd]();
  }
}
```

In the case I've totally misunderstood the question, you can connect a random integer to an element in your code like this:

```
const element = $('.cards')[random];
```

And then pass `element` to `switch` instead of `random`.

Comment: `Math.random` is not called in your code.